# How can I use custom portal colors in Portal Stories Mel

Tags: portal-2, portal-stories-mel

I know how to do it in Portal 2, using dlc3, but that doesn't seem to work in Portal Stories Mel. Do I need to name it something like `portal_stories_mel_dlc3`? maybe it's dlc 1 or 2? Maybe some other way entirely?